# Why is python dictionary empty?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a function that runs through a list and then loads a dictionary.
It prints out fine within the function but the return dict is empty?

```
 95 def getAttachmentDict(messageIds):
 96     messageTable = defaultdict(list)
 97     for id in messageIds:
 98         uri = "/message/" + id
 99         res = getMessages(uri)
100         doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(res)
101         idUrl = doc.getElementsByTagName("url")
102         alist = []
103         for i in idUrl:
104             urlData = i.childNodes[0].nodeValue
105             alist.append(urlData)
106         messageTable[id] = alist
107     print "\n"
108     for key, value in messageTable.items():
109         print "Message ID: " + key 
110         print "\n".join(value) 
111     return messageTable

169         getAttachmentDict(messageIds)
170         pdb.set_trace()
171         print messageTable
```

Message ID: MyUHRnzm7AXkFmiKocUjzn
config-safety-report.html
Message ID: RqfljNnyz63bBpGLtL4B2D
individual-report.csv

> /Work/ftpTool/acquire.py(171)main()
>   -> print messageTable
>   (Pdb) n
>   {}

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything with the return value. This is just printing some other variable you've called `messageTable`

```
169         getAttachmentDict(messageIds)
170         pdb.set_trace()
171         print messageTable
```

try this instead

```
169         messageTable = getAttachmentDict(messageIds)
170         pdb.set_trace()
171         print messageTable
```

Comment: Awesome. That works perfect. Now my question is why can I return a list e.g. messageIds and just print

Comment: Possibly you are passing messageIds as a parameter and modifying the list it references

Answer (score 1):

When you call `getAttachmentDict()`, you need to assign the result to a name (which could be `messageTable`, or any other name you want to use).  For example:

```
169         messageTable = getAttachmentDict(messageIds)
170         pdb.set_trace()
171         print messageTable
```